# I keep gettng the same debugging error on this simple springboot app

Tags: java, spring-boot

Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured.

Reason: Failed to determine a suitable driver class

Action:

Consider the following:
If you want an embedded database (H2, HSQL or Derby), please put it on the classpath.
If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to activate it (no profiles are currently active).

Comment: Hey Speedy12, welcome to SO.  
Please elaborate on the issue instead of just copy/pasting an error.  
Also, tell us what you understand from this error message and the research you did, things you tried that didn't work, etc.

Comment: can you post the code for which you're getting error?

Comment: Yo guys i fixed the error it’s ok. Thank u